# How to run two powershell functions at the same time in the same script?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm

I've done a lot of research on async calls within powershell and I haven't gotten anything to work correctly.

I need to find a way to have two separate database queries run at the same time. I have one onpremise connection and one online connection through crm dynamics.

```
function Get-OnPremiseDBQuery {
    $onPremResultsLocation = "..\results\onPremRecordsCountByEntity.txt"

        $onPremRecordSummary = @()
        foreach ($entityGroup in $entitiesArray) {
            $onPremRecordSummaryByGroup = Get-OnPremiseRecordsCountSummary -onPremConnection $onPremCRMConnection -entityNames $entityGroup
            $onPremRecordSummary += $onPremRecordSummaryByGroup

            Write-Host "ON PREM"
            Write-Host $onPremRecordSummaryByGroup | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096
        }
        Write-Output $onPremRecordSummary | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File $onPremResultsLocation -Append

}

function Get-OnlineDBQuery {
    $onlineResultsLocation = "..\results\onlineRecordsCountByEntity.txt"

        $onlineRecordSummary = @()
        foreach ($entityGroup in $entitiesArray) {
            $onlineRecordSummaryByGroup = Get-OnLineRecordsCountSummary -onlineConnection $onlineCRMConnection -entityNames $entityGroup
            $onlineRecordSummary += $onlineRecordSummaryByGroup

            Write-Host "ONLINE"
            Write-Host $onlineRecordSummaryByGroup | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096
        }
        Write-Output $onlineRecordSummary | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File $onlineResultsLocation -Append
    }

#Async Query Calls to onpremis/online DBs
##Looking to find a way to run
Get-OnPremiseDBQuery
and
Get-OnlineDBQuery
AT THE SAME TIME
```

Please help if anyone can!

Answer (score 2):

This sort of effort is what PowerShell Jobs and RunSpaces are designed for.

As for...

> I've done a lot of research on async calls within powershell and I
>   haven't gotten anything to work correctly.

Are you saying, you have leverage the below, and none of the options worked for you?

You are also not defining what you mean by..

> I haven't gotten anything to work correctly.

- What's not working?
- What response / errors are you getting?

The discussions:

> How do I run my PowerShell scripts in parallel without using Jobs?
>
> If I have a script that I need to run against multiple computers, or
>   with multiple different arguments, how can I execute it in parallel,
>   without having to incur the overhead of spawning a new PSJob with
>   Start-Job?
>
> https://serverfault.com/questions/626711/how-do-i-run-my-powershell-scripts-in-parallel-without-using-jobs
>
> Parallel processing with PowerShell
>
> > Working in parallel
>
> Whichever approach you end up taking you will be getting PowerShell to
>   run tasks in parallel. That will often require you to have additional
>   instances of PowerShell running. The resources on your admin machine –
>   CPU, memory and network bandwidth – are finite. Keep those in mind so
>   you don’t overload the machine and end up getting nothing back.
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/06/20/parallel-processing-with-powershell

See also:

> Invoke-Async - Allows you to run any cmdlet/function/scriptblock
>   asynchronously
>
> This has been tested in V2 and V3. You just provide the data set
>   (-set) such as a list of servers of configuration settings etc. The
>   param that the set belongs to (-setparam) such as ComputerName. You
>   have the ability to provide any other params with a hash via -params
>   (see examples.) The number of threads or jobs (concurrent instances)
>   can be controlled via ThreadCount
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-Async-Allows-you-to-83b0c9f0